# Exported function in DLL not found by ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have a DLL file (together with a .h and .lib) provided by a third party.
[DLL export viewer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) sees a lot of exported functions as shown below.
However I do not manage to access those functions using `ctypes` in python. I tried many functions with the same result.

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\Users\XXX\XXX\myDll.dll")
>>> lib.COM_Init()
AttributeError: function 'COM_Init' not found
```

What would be a way forward to use this library in python?

[image]

Comment: The fact that you can see the entire function signature including parameters indicates this is a C++ DLL with function name decoration decoded to show parameters.  Ctypes requires C exported functions, not C++.  In the following example you can see the name decoration and in limited cases such as the static method in this example  can even call them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72877128/235698

Comment: Another example that shows creating a C interface to a C++ class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69619946/235698

Comment: Since you have the header you might look into a Python wrapper generator like https://www.swig.org.

Comment: Thanks! I used SWIG as suggested and it worked like a charm